# Convert mongo shell query to QueryDBObject and execute using spring mongotemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongo

Below is the query which i am able to execute on my mongo shell properly.

```
db.students.update({ _id : 139 }, {$pull : { scores: {type :'homework' }}})
```

I need to execute the same thing using a Java program / Mongo Spring Template.
Could somebody help show me how to do this?

Comment: Could some body know how to do it using spring mongo template

Answer (score 0):

Your query might be similar to this:

```
UpdateResult updateResult = collection.updateOne(eq("_id", 123),
      new Document("$pull", new Document("scores",
          new Document("type", "homework"))
      )
);
```

[Here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-) you've got the documentation of the entire interface and of updateOne in specific.

You also need a connection with the database, so you might want to follow [this quick tour](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/) to get it done.

**EDIT**

For doing the same with spring mongo, you can do (as it is documented in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-update)) something like this:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

...

WriteResult wr = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(where("accounts.accountType").is(Account.Type.SAVINGS)),
  new Update().pull("students.$.scores", new Document("type", "homework")), Account.class);
```

PS: This answer probably won't work as is, it's just an example, if you want better help give larger snippets of code.

Comment: -  { "_id" : 15,"name" : "Tambra Mercure","scores" : [{"type" : "exam","score" : 69.1565022533158},{"type" : "quiz","score" : 3.311794422000724},{"type" : "homework","score" : 45.03178973642521},{"type" : "homework","score" : 42.19409476640781 }]}    ------- this is the json i need to remove homework inside array of documents.   this Is the query i am using -  mongoOperation.updateFirst(new Query(where("_id").is(15)), new Update().pull("students.$.scores", "homework"), obj.class);    @VdeVatman

Comment: HI, I got this working -                                                        BasicDBObject ob = new BasicDBObject("_id", Double.valueOf(g.getId()));
BasicDBObject ob2 = new BasicDBObject("$pull",new BasicDBObject("scores", new BasicDBObject("type","homework").append("score", dob)));                           collection.update(ob, ob2)

Comment: nice to hear, try to answer yourselve and automark your own answer as the solution.